# The problem of merging between environment branches

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, branch, pull-request

In my work place we have 3 main branches which is development, stable and production. I created a feature branch from development. when i commit a new feature on the feature branch, i always merge to development. Then I merge from development to stable. Finally merge from stable to production.

But this time one of my team mates has a code in stable branch that we can not merge to the production. So in this case how ı am suppose to merge my codes from stable to production.

Comment: If your commits are different. then you might use cherry pick commit from stable to production. for example, 
`git cherry-pick 76cada 56qwqw 46erer`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should take out the code from your team mate out of stable? Keep in mind that git is very flexible so you could either revert those revisions or you could rewrite the history of stable so that those revisions "disappear" from history (not to be done lightly, it has implications if other people are working on stable).